# import tweepy error on Mac

Tags: python-3.x, macos

I am running tweepy successfully on Windows 10 but when I run the same app on my Mac it crashes with the error below in Idle after the import tweepy statement. It seems to be something inside the tweepy module which I am not sure how to fix.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/arnoldrosielle/Desktop/PythonScripts/Twitter_Likes.py", line 9, in <module>
    import tweepy
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from tweepy.streaming import Stream, StreamListener
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 358
    def _start(self, async):
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Have you installed `tweepy`on your mac? have you activated the environment?. It looks like tweepy is nos install

Comment: It's installed.  I uninstalled and re-installed.  It's complaining about an error from the tweepy module.

Answer (score 0):

OK - so no real responses on StackOverflow so I looked a bit harder on the web and found this from here
https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1017

"stoictrader commented on May 9 •

> The same issue but on Windows10 x64 python3.7 beta, on python3.6 it
>   works fine, so seems like incompatibility with python 3.7? Okay found
>   the solution. Apparently async cannot be used as an argument name in
>   Python 3.7 So open streaming.py and replace #async with async_ it
>   fixed the error for me."

I got into streaming.py on my mac and replaced async with async_ (all occurrences).  That took care of the problem.  So indeed async cannot be used as a variable on MacOS but it is fine on Windows.  Seems like a simple fix for the developer of tweepy to change it from async to async_.

Comment: it is not related to Windows vs MacOS, `async` is a reserved word in **Python 3.5+**